# What is the optional version used for in `npm link <pkg>[@<version>]`?

Tags: node.js, npm

My understanding of what `npm link` and `npm link <pkg>` do is basically as described [in the documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/commands/npm-link):

> Package linking is a two-step process.
>
> First, npm link in a package folder will create a symlink in the global folder {prefix}/lib/node_modules/ that links to the package where the npm link command was executed. It will also link any bins in the package to {prefix}/bin/{name}. Note that npm link uses the global prefix (see npm prefix -g for its value).
>
> Next, in some other location, npm link package-name will create a symbolic link from globally-installed package-name to node_modules/ of the current folder.

So I am puzzled by what it would mean to specify the version as well in the second step of package linking (for example, `npm link my-package@3.1.4`). Isn't the version of the linked package entirely determined by the contents of the linked directory? I don't think the documentation for `npm link` explains this.

Answer (score 0):

From what i understand , **npm link** also does install any of missing dependencies.
It ensures all latest versions of dependencies are linked to global folder and non latest are installed on spot , but with its deep dependencies located in its own **node_modules**  . Installs or updates given project dependencies. If dependency version is not specified then one from package.json or latest is assumed. So if the dependency version is not specified , It will be entirely determined by the contents of the linked directory.

Answer (score 0):

There is two different behaviour to know with the link command.

The first one, is when you want to test a local package, then in fact
running `npm link ../../my-package` will be sufficient and will determined the version from the `package.json` file located in the package.

The second one, correspond to a case where you would like to tests a specific version of a remote package without impacting your `package.json`.

let say, you want to install `moment@2.29.2` without updating your `package.json` then you can run

```
npm link moment@2.29.2
```

it will install the package globally and then create a symlink in your node_modules for that package.